# 'WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I have a hybrid app I am building for iOS.  It uses Adapter authentication which has been working fine.

I recently updated from MobileFirst Studio 6.3 to 7.0.  At the same time, I updated Xcode to version 6.3.  My app continues to work fine and authenticates with the backend fine when run through the Browser Simulator, but running on a simulator or real device from Xcode, I get a connection timeout error.  The console contains this: `ERROR: Plugin 'WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.`

I see lots of questions on SO for "plugin not found or is not a CDVPlugin", but since this is a MobileFirst plugin, I wouldn't expect it to suddenly go missing.  Could this be fallout from the update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a sample project from the MFP Developer Center, or an application of your own.

Either way, you can create a new project and add the iPhone environment and compare your project's native\config.xml with the new project's native\config.xml and correct yours accordingly.

Comment: Good idea.  I did compare with a config.xml from another project and found that my project was missing just that one entry for WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.  Not sure how that happened.  I pasted it in and all is well again.

Comment: I had the same migration issue with the missing Plugin